# How to pass multiple cube textures into a uniform array of samplers?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

Say I have a uniform in a shader declared as:

```
uniform samplerCube depth_maps[];
```

And I have in the cpp side an array of texture IDs declared as:

```
vector<GLuint> depth_maps;
```

That were created by drawing to a framebuffer attached texture.

For a single texture, the code to pass the information into an array looks more or less like:

```
    glUseProgram(program);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureID);

    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "depth_maps");
    if(loc == GL_INVALID_VALUE || loc==GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
    {
        cerr << "Error returned when trying to find depth_map uniform."
            << "\nuniform: text"
            << "Error num: " << loc
            << endl;
        return;
    }

    glUniform1i(loc,1);
```

In here GL_TEXTURE1 indicates this texture is to be attached to the texture unit 1 (assume there is already a texture attached to GL_TEXTURE0).

Issue n1 there's only 2 guaranteed texture units, any after that is implementation dependent.

Issue n2, even if I have a lot of them I only know how to pass them indiovidually and independently (i.e repeat the above code for each texture I want to pass and define a new uniform for each one)

How can I pass thsi data as a contiguous uniform array?

Comment: "*Issue n1 there's only 2 guaranteed texture units, any after that is implementation dependent.*" Incorrect. The number of texture image units for the FS, even in GL 3.3, is at least 16. You're looking at compatibility stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say I have a uniform in a shader declared as:
>
> ```
> uniform samplerCube depth_maps[];
> ```

Then that would be a compile error. With one exception, arrays in GLSL *must* (eventually) be declared with a compile-time determined size.

But let's say that you have given this array a size (and you've made sure to make the `vector` containing the texture image units the same size). Setting the texture image units on a uniform array works exactly the way it does for setting *any* value on a uniform array.

You can do it individually, with a different `glUniform1i` command for each array element.

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < depth_maps.size(); ++i)
{
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << "depth_maps[" << i << "]";
  std::string name = std::move(os).str();
  GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, name.c_str());
  glUniform1i(loc, depth_maps[i]);
}
```

Or you can set them all at once.

```
GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "depth_maps");
glUniform1iv(loc, depth_maps.size(), depth_maps.data());
```